# PMD rules for Junit string

Tags: junit, pmd

We are planning to customize the PMD as per our project standards (Technology: Java and sales force).

We have `JUnits` too in our project and we have hard coded strings for `JUnit` execution.

How to set a rule to avoid the `JUnits` hard coded strings in PMD rule set?

Comment: Did you read the [PMD docs about suppression](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-4.3/suppressing.html)?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question as far as I could guess your problem. However, add code and description so that more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good Luck!

Comment: Maybe make an extra ruleset for tests, as this likely won't be the only rule to exclude for tests. You can do that by excluding/including a path in the ruleset xml with e.g. `<exclude-pattern>.*/test/.*</exclude-pattern>`, and similarly include-pattern.